# how to login and use git commands using gitbash

Tags: git, github

I have a github account with a repo to which I want to push the changes.

I executed git init in my local folder.

Logged in using gitbash using command

```
    git config --global user.name "Your Name here"
```

and

```
    git config --global user.email "your_email@domainname.com"
```

When I log in to github web site, I can see the repo there. and have checked the clone url as well.

I suppose git remote should show the repo name as well but it does not.

also when I try to clone using git clone repo name, it is not able to find the repo.

What did I miss?

Comment: Have you [generated and uploaded an SSH key](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/)?

Comment: Try running `git fetch` first to update yourself with GitHub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a remote repo. Here's what you need to do:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/your_user_name/your_repo.git
#This will set origin as your remote repository
git pull origin
```

If you later wish to push changes to the remote repo:

```
git push origin <branch_name>
#It will then prompt you for your github username and password
```